# Can BFS be used to find single source shortest path in an unweighted directed graph?

Tags: algorithm

I know BFS can be used to find shortest path from source to destination in an unweighted and undirected graph . But I wanted to know if BFS can also be used for unweighted and directed graphs or not ?

Comment: What do you think. Why shouldn't it work on directed graphs?

Comment: Yes. Even for single source to multiple destinations.

Comment: Did you try? Was there a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the BFS algorithm works for every graph with unweighted edges.

Thus it can be used for a graph with directed edges as well as long as it does not contain any weights.

Comment: BFS works for any graph but does BFS give shortest path for a unweighted directed graph ?